# Save list of txt files through referencing array [Powershell]

Tags: sql, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have a file that has some names (table_names.txt) whose contents are:

```
ALL_Dog    
ALL_Cat   
ALL_Fish
```

and another file that has some entries (test.txt) whose contents include the above names, like:

```
 INSERT INTO ALL_Dog VALUES (1,2,3)
 INSERT INTO ALL_Cat VALUES (2,3,4)
 INSERT INTO ALL_Fish VALUES (3,4,5)
```

I need to write a for loop in powershell that creates, within my current directory three separate files: ALL_Dog.txt whose contents are "INSERT INTO ALL_Dog VALUES (1,2,3)", ALL_Cat.txt whose contents are "INSERT INTO ALL_Cat VALUES (2,3,4)", ALL_Fish.txt whose contents are "INSERT INTO ALL_Fish VALUES (3,4,5)"

Here's what I have so far:

```
[string[]]$tableNameArray = (Get-Content -Path '.\table_names.txt') | foreach {$_ + " VALUES"}

[string[]]$namingArray = (Get-Content -Path '.\table_names.txt') | foreach {$_}

For($i=0; $i -lt $tableNameArray.Length; $i++)
    
{Get-Content test.txt| Select-String -Pattern $tableNameArray[$i] -Encoding ASCII | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line | Out-File -LiteralPath $namingArray[$i]}
```

The problem with what I currently have is that I cannot define the output files as .txt files, so my output files are just "ALL_Dog", "ALL_Cat", and "ALL_Fish".

The solution I'm looking for involves iteration through this namingArray to actually name the output files.

I feel like I'm really close to a solution and would mightily appreciate anyone's assistance or guidance to the correct result.

Comment: Please show us the files to input as they actually are as formatted text in the question. Now in your description, there is no telling what format they use. Are the table names for instance comma separated like in the description? Are they values, each on a separate line? Are they in fact CSV files with headers or what????

Comment: Sorry @Theo, this is my first time posting - they're .txt files with each entry a separate line - when I tried to post that, it kept saying it should be posted as code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you would like to get all lines from one file containing a certain table name and create a new textfile with these lines and having the table name as filename, with a `.txt` extension, correct?

In that case, I would do something like below:

```
$outputPath    = 'D:\Test'    # the folder where the output files should go
$inputNames    = 'D:\Test\table_names.txt'
$inputCommands = 'D:\Test\test.txt'

# make sure the table names from this file do not have leading or trailing whitespaces
$table_names = Get-Content -Path $inputNames | ForEach-Object { $_.Trim() }
$sqlCommands = Get-Content -Path $inputCommands

# loop through the table names
foreach ($table in $table_names) {
    # prepare the regex pattern \b (word boundary) means you are searching for a whole word
    $pattern = '\b{0}\b' -f [regex]::Escape($table)
    # construct the output file path and name
    $outFile = Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath ('{0}.txt' -f $table)
    # get the string(s) using the pattern and write the file
    ($sqlCommands | Select-String -Pattern $pattern).Line | Out-File -FilePath $outFile -Append
}
```